# Get data from object in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, object, frontend

I got this code from backend 10:34. My Object looks like

```
"StatusText": {

    "10": {
             "add": {
                  "34": {
                       "de": "Adding Text",
                       "en": "Adding Text"
                       }
                    },
             "de": "Main text",
             "en": "Main Text"
    }
},
```

How could I get text from Adding Text in Typescript?

My idea is I will split the code to 2 parts. The first part should be shown the main text and the second part should be shown the adding text.

What I tried:

```
const statusText = fetched.data[0].StatusText;
const split = statusCode.split(':');
    const mainStatus = statusText[split[0]];
    const addedStatus = statusText[split[1]];
  
    let mainStatusText = mainStatus.en;
    let addedStatusText = addedStatus.en;
```

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:angular] or even [tag:typescript]? This seems like a fairly trivial JavaScript question (and if you're not familiar with JavaScript I'd strongly recommend picking up the basics before trying to add TypeScript and Angular on top).

Comment: First get comfertable with javascript. Next (or if you still just want to dive right into angular) do the [angular tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial), it is very well written IMO. That will give you a good foundation from where to start including how to handle server responses (json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't see a relation with [angular](https://xpertuto.com/) this is a [javascript](https://www.javascript.com/).
this is a good post from [mozilla developer documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) if you want to learn how to work with objects.

Now let me back to your example.
if i see your code i don't see why you are splitting your object , you can access to your property directly using this syntax :

```
data[property][property2]...
```

in your case you can use this :

```
let mainStatusText = fetched.data[0].StatusText['10']['en'];
let addedStatusText = fetched.data[0].StatusText['10']['add']['34']['en'];
```

you can replace ['x'] by a simple '.x'

Answer (score 0):

You question is not clear at all.

If you want to access the "Adding Text" string, you must convert the response from JSON then access it like:

```
data.StatusText.10.add.34.de
```